# How to do a POST request from within Hubot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, jira, hubot

I'm trying to code a Hubot listener that would automatically create a JIRA issue from a specific chat dialogue. Here's the example (I used Hubot-Rocketchat boilerplate code from here: https://github.com/RocketChat/hubot-rocketchat-boilerplate)

```
module.exports = (robot) => {
    robot.hear(/^#alerts (.*)/i, (res) => {
        const jiraurl="https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue/"
        const jiraproject="ALERTS"

        text = res.match[1]

        data = JSON.stringify({
            "fields": {
                "project":
                {
                    "key": `#{jiraproject}`
                },
                "summary": `#{text}`,
                "description": "Задача создана автоматически из RocketChat",
                "issuetype": {
                "name": "Инцидент"
                }
            }
        })

        /* res.reply(data) */
        res.reply(`Создаю задачу в JIRA: ${text}`)
        robot.http(jiraurl)
            .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .post(data) (err, response, body) =>

                if err
                    res.send `Ошибка: #{err}`
                    return
    })
}
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: What is the problem? You want to make a request with a `POST` method, but you don't know how to do it? or What?

Comment: I got lost in JS syntax trying to do it. For some reason I get:

  robot.http(jiraurl)
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .